# Can't find specific services inside dist folder when building angular project?

Tags: angular, build

This is my project structure:

[image]

Now I am building the project and I can find the dist folder containing an index.html, main.js, styles.css, assets-folder and some other stuff that the project is depending on. Now the thing is, that this library I did, has its entry point in a method of a service (output-dialog.service.ts).
I was uploading this lib on nexus and installed it via npm i  and it worked. But when I import the lib into a components .ts file like
import {OutputDialogService} from "", it can not find the module. I think, that the service can't be found.
Take a look at the dist folder:

[image]

What do you think? Did the build process of the project fail? Does the dist folder look correct? What could be the reason for my other project to not find that specific service?